# React How to pass hook value to CreateContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-context

I have a `SideBarBlurChange` component, I need to pass a value called `values` inside the `BlurChangeValue` array, which is inside `CreateContext`.

On the Internet I did not find a suitable example, I hope that it is possible to reolize, because so far I have no other options for reolizing. I want to show a screenshot of what I want to do to make it clearer for you

[image]

```
export const BlurContext = createContext({
    BlurChangeValue: [],
});

export default function SideBarBlurChange(props) {

    const ls = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem('values'));
    const [values, SetValues] = useState(ls ? [ls] : [20]);

    const SaveChanges = () => {
        localStorage.setItem('values', values);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <BlurContext.Provider values={values}>
                // jsx
            </BlurContext.Provider>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Assign the value to the provider in the correct structure: `<BlurContext.Provider value={{ BlurChangeValue: values }}>`

Answer (score 2):

A lot of mistakes

1. `const ls = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem('values'));`
seem localStorage.values is number, but
 `localStorage.setItem('values', values);`
set as array
2. `createContext({ BlurChangeValue: [], });` create a Object context with property BlurChangeValue, but `<BlurContext.Provider value={values}>` provide array values

```
const [values, setValues] = useState(()=> JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('values') || '[20]'));
const saveValues = ()=> {
    localStorage.setItem('values', JSON.stringify(newValues));
}
return (
<BlurContext.Provider values={{BlurChangeValue: values}} >
)
;
```

Comment: [Context.Provider](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider) property should be `value` not `values`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work, please pay attention to the screenshot in the Provider, I get the value, but when I try to get this value in the SideBar component I get undefined [screenshot](https://ibb.co/rGXpM9X)

Comment: Maybe this is due to the fact that I did not import the SideBar inside the SideBarBlurChange?